# What is the plain TeX equivalent of \rule in LaTeX?

Tags: rules, plain-tex

For various reasons, I have to use TeX rather than LaTeX for a short document.  I need to be able to insert a short blank underline within a paragraph. In LaTeX, this would be done easily with `\rule{length}{thickness}`.  What is the plain TeX equivalent?

Comment: `\def\rule#1#2{\leavevmode\vrule width #1 height #2 depth 0pt\relax}`

Comment: That almost works, but it seems to be ignoring the height argument.

Comment: I forgot to set `depth`.

Comment: I ended up using a slight modification with just one argument:

\def\rule#1{\leavevmode\vrule width #1 height 0.45pt depth 0pt\relax}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a long underline you can use `\hrulefill` inside a box:

```
Some text with no real sense, just to fill
\hbox to 6em{\hrulefill} some space.

\bye
```

[image]